# Regex to allow some special characters c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have to check whether a string contains special characters or not but I can allow these 5 special characters in it `.()_-`

i have written my regex as

```
var specialCharacterSet = "^[()_-.]";
var test = Regex.Match("a!", specialCharacterSet);
var isValid = test.Success;
```

but its throwing an:

> error parsing "^[()_-.]" - [x-y] range in reverse order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have specified a range with `-`. Place it at the end:

```
[()_.-]
```

Otherwise the range is not correct: the lower boundary symbol `_` appears later in the character table than the upper bound symbol `.`:

[image]

Also, if you plan to check if *any* of the character inside a string belongs to this set, you should remove `^` that checks only at the beginning of a string.

To test if a string meets some pattern, use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Indicates whether the regular expression finds a match in the input string.

```
var specialCharacterSet = "[()_.-]";
var test = Regex.IsMatch("a!", specialCharacterSet);
```

**UPDATE**

To *accept any string value that doesnt contains the five characters*, you can use

```
var str = "file.na*me";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(str, @"[()_.-]"))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: Valid!", str));
else
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: Invalid!", str));
```

[image]

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Vqre2p)

Comment: So my regex should be     var specialCharacterSet = "^[A-Za-z0-9()_.-]+$"; to allow alpha numeric and those 5 special characters that i mentioned

Comment: If you plan to match any Unicode letters and numbers, I suggest using `\w` as it matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`: `^[\w().-]+$`. The `\p{N}` shorthand Unicode category class matches all kinds of digits, `\p{L}` matches any kind of letters.

Comment: regex should accept any string value that doesnt contains the five characters i have mention. i think the above regex i commented will do. please let me know if it wont

Comment: I updated the answer with exact code for the requirement above.

Comment: i used this but its is saying that this "file.na*me" where it shouldnt be

Comment: See updated answer, I think it is now working as expected.

Comment: I dont think that  will do because i want those characters in my filename or whatever name

Comment: But the `file.na*me` is invalid when validated with my code. Please check my edited code example, and see proof.

Comment: "To accept any string value that doesnt contains the five characters, you can use " its just reverse i can allow these five

Comment: Excuse me, you mean to say the string *can* have them, or *must* have them? I see no point in *can* since the string might as well contain `§`, so why checking for it? Just remove `!` and you will have a reverse functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88105/discussion-between-silly-volley-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 2):

**You can use** `^[()_\-.]` or `^[()_.-]`  if you use special characters then best use `\` before any special characters (which are used in regex special char.).

Answer (score 1):

```
[()_.-]
```

Keep `-` at end or `escape` it to avoid it forming an invalid range.`-` inside a `character class` forms a range.Here

`_` is decimal `95`

`.` is decimal `46`.

So it is forming an invalid range from `95 to 46`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var specialCharacterSet = "^[()_.-]";
        var test = Regex.IsMatch("a!", specialCharacterSet);
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all special characters in a pattern to text using Regex.Escape(). Suppose you already have `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape("[");
```

then check like this

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("ab[c", pattern)) Console.WriteLine("found");
```

Microsoft doesn't tell about escape in the tutorial. I learned it from Perl.

Answer (score -1):

The best way in terms of C# is [()_\-\.], because . and - are reserved characters for regex. You need to use an escape character before these reserved characters.

Comment: `.` is **not** a special character inside character class and `-` doesn't need to be escaped when at first or last posiiton.

Comment: My program did not work until I treated these characters as special characters. Just for an example, what do you think about the following expression?
@"^([A-Za-z0-9&+().- ]*)$"
Do you think it will allow a user to enter . and - characters as an input?

Comment: Could you please try it your self using visual studio 2019. If you are successful to allow a user to enter . and - character using  @"^([A-Za-z0-9&+().- ]*)$" then please post your c# and HTML code here. So that others like me can learn.